# First-order Taylor expansion for a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $u:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ and $u$ has continuous partial derivatives prove that

(a) $u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x }h +\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y }k +\epsilon_1$

(b) $v(x+h,y+k)-v(x,y)=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x }h +\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y }k +\epsilon_2$

where $\dfrac{\epsilon_1}{h+ik}\to 0$ and  $\dfrac{\epsilon_2}{h+ik}\to 0$.

**My try:**
$u(x+h,y+k)-u(x,y)=\dfrac{u(x+h,y+k)-u(x+h,y)}{k}k+\dfrac{u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}{h}h=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} u(x+h,y)k+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,y)h$

Similarly the other case will follow.

What I am having trouble is that how I should incorporate $\epsilon _1$ here and give the requisite conditions that $\dfrac{\epsilon_1}{h+ik}\to 0$.

Comment: did you want to write $k$ instead of the second $h$ on the r.h.s in (a), (b) ?

Comment: Your try is not accurate enough. There is no equality between the the middle term and the right term. You should revise the definition of the derivative of a function of two variables.

Comment: yes you got it right@uniquesolution

Comment: please do provide an answer which ever way you think is possible @uniquesolution

Comment: The appearance of (b) is bizarre. It's just the same formula with $v$ instead of $u$. What is the point of it?

Answer (score 1):

You applied the mean value theorem incorrectly. It says 
$$
 {u(x+h,y+k)-u(x+h,y)} =  u_y(x+h,y+\theta_1 k)k $$ 
and 
$$
 {u(x+h,y)-u(x,y)}  =  u_x(x+\theta_2 h,y)h
$$
where $\theta_1,\theta_2\in (0,1)$. The continuity of partial derivatives yields 
$$u_y(x+h,y+\theta_1 k) = u_y(x  ,y  ) + \eta_1(h,k)   $$
and 
$$u_x(x+\theta_2 h ,y) = u_y(x  ,y  ) + \eta_2(h)   $$
where $\eta_1(h,k)$ and $\eta_2(h)$ tend to zero as $(h,k)\to (0,0)$. Hence, the quantity 
$$\epsilon_1 = \eta_1(h,k) k+ \eta_2(h) h$$ has the desired property.